# Integrate $\int_1^\infty\lfloor x\rfloor e^{-x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus

How can I calculate $\int_1^\infty\lfloor x\rfloor e^{-x}\,dx$, where $\lfloor \cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function? I need help on it and integration by parts does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be reduced to a summation
$$
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_1\lfloor x\rfloor e^{-x}dx&=\sum_1^\infty n\int_n^{n+1}e^{-x}dx\\
&={e-1\over e}\sum_1^\infty n e^{-n}
\\
\end{align}
$$
[Wolfram Alpha says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n+e%5E%7B-n%7D+from+1+to+infinity) the final sum is $e/ (1-e)^2$ so the answer must be $1/(1-e)$.

Comment: The summation can be done by summing $\sum_n e^{-\beta n}$ using geometric series, then differentiating at $\beta = 1$.

Comment: @NemisL. Thanks for filling me in.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The integral can be written as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_k^{k+1}k e^{-x} \, dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\int_1^\infty\lfloor x\rfloor e^{-x}\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}\lfloor x\rfloor e^{-x}\,dx=\cdots$$